# Add custom CSS to GTranslate plugin (Wordpress) - margin bottom

Tags: css, wordpress, translation

I installed the Gtranslate plugin on my wordpress site and I would like to add some custom CSS to personalize the widget.
I would like the flags to go under each other. I would also like to add a margin at the bottom.[Widget settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaFaU.png)

I tried to add CSS with the selector .gtranslate_wrapper but it doesn't work...
For example:

```
.gtranslate_wrapper{
     margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

very easy, use the element ID, problem solved.

```
#gt_float_wrapper{padding-top: 50px!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem
you probably just need to add !important in front of every modification you wanna make
in your case it'd look like this:

```
.gtranslate_wrapper{
     margin-bottom: 50px !important;
}
```